# Why doesn't the Aquamacs text-mode-hook I add in my .emacs file seem to run?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, hook

I'm running Aquamacs 2.4 (based on Emacs 23.3.50.1) on my Macbook, OS 10.7.5.  I have the following line in my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
```

I think that this line should cause visual line mode to be enabled whenever text-mode is, but it isn't.  It fails to work even when this line is the only line in my .emacs file.  Why might this be?

Many thanks!

Comment: This should work, are you sure you're using a text mode? `M-x` `text-mode` `RET`. You could also try to see if the hook is executed with: `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (message "Hello from text-mode-hook")))`, `M-x` `text-mode` `RET` and then check the `*Message*` buffer.

Comment: @Daimrod This comment set me on the path to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting (and some TFM reading) prompted by Daimrod's comment, I learned that the problem arose from the way Aquamacs does configuration.  It loads the `~/.emacs` file, but that's the first file it loads of four, and my `text-mode-hook` was being overwritten by one of the files loaded after it

Specifically, the order (according to the Aquamacs manual section 4.3, *customizing Aquamacs*) is:

```
~/.emacs
~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el
/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el (for all users)
~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el
```

My addition to the `text-mode-hook` was being overwritten by a line in the `customizations.el` file, which was why visual line mode wasn't loading.

The manual also says that users shouldn't use ~/.emacs for customizations, but the last Preferences.el file instead, so I've moved everything in .emacs to my Preferences.el.  Everything now works as I expect.